# How to remove Signing Cerificate Apple Developer in Xcode Mac

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am trying to deploy Flutter Application on my Iphone and I used my old icloud account as Developer how can I change the Signing Certificate Apple Developer id to match it with the id on the device to upload the Flutter application. I have tried several solutions first by deleting the KeyChain password but it is difficult to track and even when deleted nothing happened.

Any step by step guide will help to restart from the very begining. It is the first time for me to use Ios

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must have valid provisioning profile and development certificate which registered your device.  Go through these steps to understand requirement to run app on iOS device.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-your-app-in-simulator-or-on-a-device